# rails - undefined method all for forum:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am trying to implement a forum page using the tutorial in this [page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-a-forum-from-scratch-with-ruby-on-rails/)!. Here Forum is a model. This is the controller code:

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_required, :except => [:index, :show]

  def index
    @forums = Forum.all
  end

  def show
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @forum = Forum.new
  end

  def create
    @forum = Forum.new(params[:forum])
    if @forum.save
      redirect_to @forum, :notice => "Successfully created forum."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    if @forum.update_attributes(params[:forum])
      redirect_to @forum, :notice  => "Successfully updated forum."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:id])
    @forum.destroy
    redirect_to forums_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed forum."
  end
end
```

the error is :

```
undefined method `all' for Forum:Module
```

Here is the forum model ( models/forum.rb):

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy

  #method to find the most recent forum topics
  def most_recent_post  
  topic = Topic.first(:order => 'last_post_at DESC', :conditions => ['forum_id = ?', self.id])  
  return topic  
end  
end
```

How can i rectify this error? I am new to ROR and unable to find a proper solution for this error.

Comment: please, provide your Forum model source code

Comment: Redo Step 4. Forum is not a module but a model in app/models

Comment: @ThelrishGuy sorry about the mistake in the question, i had done it as specified.

Comment: @AlexanderKobelev i have provide forum model source code.

Answer (score 5):

The error above is saying there is no method defined for the `Module` `Forum`. However, the definition of `Forum` clearly shows that's a class, not a module.

The only explanation is that you have another definition of Forum somewhere in your application, where you define it as a `Module`, that is loaded before the model and it conflicts with your application.

**Be very careful you didn't call your application `Forum`**, otherwise the main application namespace will conflict with your model (there is a high chance that's the problem).
In this case, you either rename your application or (easier) the model. In fact, the application namespace is defined as module.

Search the source code of your application for a Forum module definition and remove it. It may also be in a gem (very unlikely, but not impossible) so make sure you know the source code of the dependencies your are using.

Answer (score 1):

This could be something to do with your routes.

Try in `config/routes.rb`

`root :to => 'forums#index'`

instead of

`map.root :controller => 'forums'`

It's a rails 2/3 thing and I think this tutorial is written in 2.

If you are trying to learn Rails, I recommend [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Comment: hey i had made that change earlier but still ended up getting the same error

Comment: Yeah, I think Simone nailed it. It's likely that a Forum Module is already defined.

Answer (score 1):

Naming the app and the controller with the same name, somehow, the class from the will be interpreted as a model. your_class.class should return 'Class'. I don't have much experience, but that's what i've noticed. Deleting the app and building it again with the same methods but different name worked. Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, when I rename my app to something else than my model's name, it starts to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I created a directory in `app/controllers` with the same name as the model. Removing the directory fixed the issue.

For example:

```
app/controllers/communication
```

```
app/models/communication.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason happened because you generated your rails app as Forum. When you do that the db name is going to be Forum and **MORE IMPORTANTLY** the application module inside /config/application.db is going to be called Forum too and that's where the confusion gets. To fix this go to your config/application.rb and change the module name to e.g : ForumApp and do same for the DB though that's not necessary.